# Get a post's ID

Tags: posts, id

How do I get a post's ID? I know I can use the_ID(), but I have to use it in The Loop. How can I get the post's ID without the loop? Because I think using the loop just to find the post's ID will slow down my script. Maybe i'm wrong. Please help me :)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on a singular page, sometime after `init` and all the query variables have all ben set up you can use `get_queried_object_id` or `get_queried_object`.

```
<?php
if (is_singular()) {
    $post_id = get_queried_object_id();

    // or get the whole object
    $post = get_queried_object();

    // or do the first one differently
    $post_id = get_queried_object()->ID;
}
```

You can also just "false start" the loop and get what you need. It probably won't slow down your script: WordPress fetchs all the queried posts at once, so the database hit has already happened. You might use this if you're not a singular page and need to get the first post's ID.

```
<?php
// start the loop
the_post();

// get the ID
$post_id = get_the_ID();

// back to normal
rewind_posts();
```

Comment: Thank you! Where is the documentation for your first answer? I can't find that in the wordpress codex..

Comment: You can look up the fucntion themselves in the codex, but the codex is not a tutorial site: it's up to you glue everything together.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the post object saved as a variable somewhere (I assume that this is the case) you can get it's ID by `$you_post_object->ID`. If this is not the case then you should post some of your code so that we know what you are dealing with.

Comment: I don't have a post object saved in a variable (I don't know what is a post object or how to create one). And what do you mean post some of my code? All I need is to put the post ID in a variable ex: $id = get_the_ID(), but to use this function, I need to put it in a loop, and I don,t know if this is the good way to do it.